# Datetime with 5 top showing

Tags: php, datetime, limit

I did try to do "Limit 5" or "MAX" date but it is seem not working what I expected. Can you point it out where I need to look up because I did look up all over place and seem not outcome what I expected. As you can see "date" and "amount" - it is for mychart java. Please help!

```sql
SELECT reading_time AS date, pressCount AS amount FROM NodeData ORDER BY reading_time DESC WHERE nodeId ='2';
```

SQL Table Structure - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

[image: Table showed]

Comment: What do you want  about data response !?

Comment: Please describe more to let everyone not just you to understand what you want. You are showing only your data screenshot from PhpMyAdmin and some SQL statement. What is its result? What would you like the results of it to be?

Comment: umm, put `where` after the table name followed by the `order by` clause, and finally the `limit` wont give parse error. `SELECT reading_time AS date, pressCount AS amount FROM NodeData where nodeId = 2
order by reading_time desc limit 5`.

Answer (score 0):

as Bagus told the query has a false Syntax.

Simple execution syntax is

```
- SELECT
- FROM
- WHERE
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT
```